# Override in a list of a parent class in C#

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

In my XNA game, I have a foreach loop that runs from a list of sprites (SpriteList). This list is a mixture of its child classes.

In my update method I'm using:

```
foreach (Sprites s in SpriteList)
{
    s.Update();
}
```

This is calling the update method of the Sprites class (which is abstract), but I want it to use the update method of the child classes that it is made of.

I have tried making the update method of the Sprites class abstract and virtual, and both have been creating errors when I call the methods

**EDIT:**

My sprites class is:

```
public abstract class Sprites
{
    public Texture2D SpriteTexture;
    public Rectangle SpriteRectangle;
    public SpriteTypes SpriteType;
    public Color SpriteColour;
    public bool SpriteAlive = false;

    public Sprites(Texture2D TextureIn, Rectangle RectangleIn)
    {
        SpriteTexture = TextureIn;
        SpriteRectangle = RectangleIn;
        SpriteType = SpriteTypes.Sprite;
        SpriteColour = Color.White;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // This is what's being called, rather than the update methods of the child classes
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code or at least a minimum working example?

Comment: Did you make the subclass `Update` method `override` the base method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the method `virtual` in the `Sprites` class (or `abstract` if there is no implementation in that class) *and* use the `override` keyword when you declare the method in each of the child classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
public abstract class Sprites
{
    public Texture2D SpriteTexture;
    public Rectangle SpriteRectangle;
    public SpriteTypes SpriteType;
    public Color SpriteColour;
    public bool SpriteAlive = false;

    public Sprites(Texture2D TextureIn, Rectangle RectangleIn)
    {
        SpriteTexture = TextureIn;
        SpriteRectangle = RectangleIn;
        SpriteType = SpriteTypes.Sprite;
        SpriteColour = Color.White;
    }

    // note the `abstract` keyword here,
    // which means "this method is to be implemented in child classes" 
    public abstract void Update();    
}

public class ChildSprites : Sprites
{
     public override void Update()//note `override` keyword
     {
         // ...
     }
}
```